# Linux Grouping and Counting Files by attribute

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to return a list of the months that files were created using the following code.

```
ls -l|awk '{A[$6":"]++}END{for (i in A){print i" "A[i]}}'
```

I am using the below code to validate each output.

```
ls -la | grep -c "Jan"
```

However as you can see from my output:

```
: 1
Jan: 19
Feb: 11
Mar: 28
Apr: 10
May: 14
Jun: 24
Jul: 4
Aug: 16
Sep: 10
Oct: 30
Nov: 4
Dec: 1
```

[Output of ls|grep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2VLf.jpg)

I end up with 1 record showing no date. Also both January and December are short by 1. Can anyone assist?

Comment: `Also both January and December are short by 1`  `ls | grep` is not a reliable way of finding the count. What if there is a file called `JanFiles`. The `grep` just adds that in the count.

Comment: Interesting, hadn't considered that, I'm going to check the files now and see if that is what is throwing my counts off.

Comment: Your approach of parsing `ls` output is wrong, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Unfortunately you already accepted an answer based on that incorrect approach so post a new question if you'd like to know how to really solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way using `awk` and `sort`

```
$ ls -l | awk '$6!=""{m[$6]++}END{for(i in m){printf "%s : %s%s",i,m[i],ORS }}' | sort -k1M
Jan : 7
Mar : 1
Apr : 8
Aug : 2
```

The problem comes with the first line of `ls -l` which doesn't contain a month field

Comment: Thank you. That works to remove the empty one but I'm still unclear why the values of Dec and Jan are short by one.  Also while I'm understanding the majority of the code, can you explain the ORS? It's not something I am familiar with.

Comment: @RyanG The `ORS` is the `awk` bultin for the output record separator which is usually a newline. Using `ORS` can help us **not** hard-code the newline escape sequences like `\n` which may vary among systems.

Comment: @RyanG  But I am not sure what is happening with the values of `the values of Dec and Jan`. As a sidenote, I recommend using the `-a` parameter of the `ls` for it to show the hidden files too..

Comment: I am actually using -la and a sort as well to ensure they are all in the correct order, but I appreciate the input as it helps me to know I'm on the right path. It bothers me that I can't understand the short values.

Comment: @RyanG Could you explain what you mean by `short values`? Did you mean stuff like `ORS`?

Comment: I meant the short values in Jan and Dec, I just manually checked the files and the grep count was incorrect.

Comment: Oh I see.. Could you run `ls -la | awk '{$0=$6}1' | grep -c 'Jan'` and check the cound @RyanG

Comment: The problem was the hidden files

Comment: @EdMorton I completely agree with you. But this was more of a test op I guess but with the wrong example. Also, *not parsing* the `ls` would be more applicable in case of `parsing` filenames from its output imho.